# Angularjs array changes its syntax when it has only one record

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using an `angularjs array` to store the record data(table rows) received by using the `http.get` rest API and printing using an ng-repeat. The problem is whenever there is only one record retrieved through rest API, ng-repeat doesn't print the record. ng-repeat only print the records when API retrieves more than one record.

```
 $scope.details=[];
  var lrequ = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://example.com/execSQL?sql=mysqlquery",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
$http(lrequ).then(function(response){
    $scope.details=response.data.platform.record;
     alert($scope.details.fieldname);
     alert($scope.details[0].fieldname)
    }, function(){alert("failure");});
```

this is my ng-repeat line,

```
 <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="dat in details | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
    <p style="color:#4C97C8;" class="lead"><strong>{{dat.summary}}</strong></p>
</div>
```

**I found where is the problem causing-**

1.When rest api throws only one record, i shouldnt use ng-repeat instead i should use scope variable directly in the view and this alert($scope.details.fieldname) inside controller works but not alert($scope.details[0].fieldname).

2.When rest api throws more than one record, i have to use ng-repeat and this alert($scope.details[0].fieldname) works.

How to solve this? How can i show data in `view` in both cases?

Comment: No matter if the API returns 1 record or more, using `ng-repeat` is good. Please show us what is inside `response.data` and try removing the filter

Comment: If you know there's going to be 1 record, you can convert it to an array: Array.from(data); then your ng-repeat should work.

Comment: Seems to be a bad implementation of the rest api. If you're asking for a list of items, you should expect a list of items, even if it is only one item

Comment: After response.data assign output to $scope.details variable- alert($scope.details) gives [object object] as an response when it as 1 record. It gives [object object],[object object] as an response when it as 2 record @Weedoze

Comment: I agree with devqon, your rest api should return list of objects in both of case either it have multiple object or single object.